# How do I add a marker where I click (React/Nextjs google maps api)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, next.js, mouseevent

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on the map, I can place a marker on the location of the mouse click. (deleting the previous marker) Here is my code:

```js
const guessCoords = null;

const handleMapClick = (e) => {
  let lat = e.latLng.lat();
  let lng = e.latLng.lng();
  guessCoords = { lat, lng };
};

function Map() {
  const center = useMemo(() => ({ lat: 44, lng: -80 }), []);

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      zoom={10}
      center={center}
      streetView={false}
      mapTypeId="roadmap"
      mapContainerClassName="w-full h-full absolute"
      mapTypeControls={false}
      onClick={(e) => handleMapClick(e)}
    >
      <Marker position={guessCoords} />
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}
```

I'm using NextJS. I've looked and haven't found anything for my use case.

Comment: Move `guessCoords` into React state using `useState`, e.g. `const [guessCoords, setGuessCoords] = useState(null);`. Then call `setGuessCoords({ lat, lng })` on the `onClick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this should be a comment to your question and not an answer but stackoverflow does not allow me to write a comment ... so I try to help you this way!

What component are you using for the Google Maps integration? I can recommend google-map-react to you, works really good for us.

I recommend you to fix your typescript code!
*guessCoords* should not be const because it is changed in your click method.
This code fragment is correct in typescript:

```
let guessCoords;

const handleMapClick = (e) => {
  const lat = e.latLng.lat();
  const lng = e.latLng.lng();
  guessCoords = { lat, lng };
};
```